# signup form -- Rails + foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

Im using foundation-rails and creating a signup form.

This is what Im using to create a password field in a div.

```
<%= text_field_tag "password", "", placeholder: "Password", required: true, type: "password" %>
<small class="error">Invalid</small>
```

For the confirm password field, I am setting it up similarly, in a div:

```
 <%= text_field_tag "password_confirmation", "", placeholder: "Reenter password" , required: true, type: "password" %>
 <small class="error >Invalid</small>
```

I want to use foundation's `data-equalto="password"` for the password confirmation to make sure the same password is entered. But Im unable to add it to Rails(it does not work).

any help ?

Comment: you have a typo `<small class="error >Invalid</small> `, what do you want to do with `data-equalto="password"`?

Comment: I want to add a password confirmation field. So that the confirm password is checked to be equal to the password before submitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any HTML option you need:

```
<%= text_field_tag "password", "", placeholder: "Password", required: true, type: "password", data: { equalto: "browser" } %>
```